# Correlation for Null Values

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, data-analysis

In my dataframe, I have some Null values. I want to calculate the correlation, so does my Null values affect my correlation value or shall I replace the Null values with 0 and then find the correlation?

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate correlation with null values in your dataset.
You need to impute your columns to get rid of the null values.
Don't replace the null values with 0. Use mean or median of the columns to replace the null values as it will be more related to the data in the columns as compared to 0